# Docker: Only one docker container running when I start two containers from the same container ID

Tags: docker

In scenario 1 and 3, two docker containers are running. But in scenario 2, when I start the container with same container ID(twice), I see only one container running. What is the logic/reason behind this?(I was expecting two instances to be running)

***SCENARIO 1:***

$ docker create busybox ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
163a5907dcfd7f37be0debb1153f0307a962a7709aa6c418ddab1f833a3bc4b8

$ docker create busybox ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
178c343d16fe7930b78532d234e735f203cad6a7fa3d932d12c71a433922c2b2

$ docker start 163a5907dcfd7f37be0debb1153f0307a962a7709aa6c418ddab1f833a3bc4b8
163a5907dcfd7f37be0debb1153f0307a962a7709aa6c418ddab1f833a3bc4b8

$ docker start  178c343d16fe7930b78532d234e735f203cad6a7fa3d932d12c71a433922c2b2
178c343d16fe7930b78532d234e735f203cad6a7fa3d932d12c71a433922c2b2

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

178c343d16fe        busybox             "ping www.google.com"   About a minute ago   Up 11 seconds                           jovial_maxwell

163a5907dcfd        busybox             "ping www.google.com"   About a minute ago   Up 3 seconds                            relaxed_hofstadter

***SCENARIO 2:***

$ docker start 163a5907dcfd7f37be0debb1153f0307a962a7709aa6c418ddab1f833a3bc4b8

$ docker start 163a5907dcfd7f37be0debb1153f0307a962a7709aa6c418ddab1f833a3bc4b8

$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

163a5907dcfd        busybox             "ping www.google.com"   3 minutes ago       Up 4 seconds                            relaxed_hofstadter

***SCENARIO 3:***

$ docker run busybox ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

$ docker run busybox ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

a0880fa44941        busybox             "ping www.google.com"   6 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds                            xenodochial_bohr

df85aab07d43        busybox             "ping www.google.com"   13 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds                           trusting_keldysh

Comment: I think you might be confusing `docker start` and `docker run`.  `start` starts the main process in an existing container; it never creates a new container, and using it at all is a little unusual.  `run` creates a new container from an image, and that seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker create` or `docker run`, a container is created from the given image, it is assigned a unique ID, and that container is run. Thus, if you run the same command twice, you get two containers, each with distinct ID, for the same image and you can run them separately.

When you start a container by its ID, the command applies to that particular container. When you restart it, it will not do anything because that container is already running.